# Static variable link error, C++

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, linkage

Consider this code.

```
//header.h
int x;

//otherSource.cpp
#include "header.h"

//main.cpp
#include "header.h"
...
int main()
{

}
```

In this case compiler erred with the message. "fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"

but when I add static before x, it compiles without errors.

And here is the second case.

```
//header.h

class A
{
public:
    void f(){}
    static int a;
};

int A::a = 0;

/otherSource.cpp
#include "header.h"

//main.cpp
#include "header.h"
...
int main()
{

}
```

In this case compiler again erred with multiple declaration.

Can anybody explain me the behavior we static variables in classes and in global declarations?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definition (where you initialize the static variabe) should be in one *and only one* source file.  Don't place it in a header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the static member variable is that you have the definition occur in the header file.  If you `#include` the file in multiple source files, you have multiple definitions of the static member variable.

To fix this, the header file should consist only of this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
// In the header file
class A
{
public:
    void f(){}
    static int a;
};
#endif
```

The definition of the static variable `a` should be in one *and only one* module.  The obvious place for this is in your `main.cpp`.

```
#include "header.h"
int A::a = 0;  // defined here
int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `x` as `extern` in `header.h` to tell the compiler that `x` will be defined somewhere else:

```
extern int x;
```

Then define `x` **once** in the source file which you think is most fitting.
For example in `otherSource.cpp`:

```
int x = some_initial_value;
```